# Typescript declaration file for msnodesql module

Tags: sql-server, typescript

Does anyone know if a type declaration file msnodesql.d.ts for the SQL Server database driver for node.js exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find definitions at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

The file here: [msnodesql-0.2.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/Definitions/msnodesql-0.2.d.ts)

Comment: Boris, Thanks. But that is not complete :( I tried to complete by adding to the interface connection but got stuck on the queryRaw() function as its second param could be an array of params or it could be a callback function and I don't know how to represent it!

Comment: Here is the Connection interface declaration                        `interface Connection { 
        close(callback: (err: Error) => void);
        queryRaw(query: string, paramsOrCallback, callback?: (err: Error, results: any[]) => void);
        query(query: string, paramsOrCallback, callback?: (err: Error, results: any[]) => void);
        beginTransaction(callback?: (err: Error) => void);
        commit(callback: (err: Error) => void);
        rollback(callback: (err: Error) => void);
    }`

Comment: Kasim, you can represent the param or callback parameter by using two overloads as I have done in the module.